# Why doesn't sonar-maven-plugin fetch sources dir from pom.xml

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm using maven and sonar qube since long ago and am used to get analysis running with sonar qube fetching source files from pom.xml.

But after updating sonar qube from 5.x to 6.7.3 I noticed this is not working any more for my projects.

The projects pom.xml contains
    `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`

But when analysis is running it states "Source paths: pom.xml".

So I have to add 
    `<sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>` 
to get it running again.

Why doesn't sonar qube fetch the source folder from pom.xml?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0.905</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.4.0.905</version>
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>sonar-run</id>
             <phase>verify</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>sonar</goal>
               </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Maybe the executions section is not necessary for you.

Comment: You are right, that I should use the newer group name. Thanks for this hint. But this is only a naming thing and does not change any behaviour.

Comment: In this section you can define other path different from the folder from pom.xml. Example: <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>

Comment: If you read my question, you'll see that I already added sonar.sources to get things running. But this should not be necessary.